# Передача нескольких результатов выполнения функции в lambda-функцию в разные переменные

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, анонимная-функция

Коллеги, буду сразу на примерах показывать, думаю, так нагляднее.

Есть функция, которая возвращает несколько объектов (для примера возьмем два). Вернувшиеся значения можно получить в одну переменную, тогда это будет кортеж или в несколько переменных, тогда они распакуются в каждую переменную.

```
def func():
    return 12, 10

# вот так будет кортеж
x = func()
print(x)

# вот так будут две разные переменные
x, y = func()
(print(x, y))
```

Я ожидаю, что по той же логике я передам результаты в анонимную функцию. Смотрим:

```
def func():
    return 12, 10

dic = (lambda x: {'12': x[0], '10': x[1]})(func())
print(dic)
```

Нормально, как ожидалось. Передали кортеж, распаковали в теле функции.

Теперь передаем в две переменные:

```
def func():
    return 12, 10

dic = (lambda x, y: {'12': x, '10': y})(func())
print(dic)
```

Нет, так не работает, потому что:

> TypeError: () missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Можно ли как-то это сделать? Что я упускаю?

**UPT**

Пока писал вопрос, возник ответ. Но уже столько понаписал, что пожалел времени, поэтому опубликую ответ сам. Извините, спасибо!

P.S. Но если есть другие решения - буду очень рад!

Comment: "Я ожидаю, что по той же логике я передам результаты в анонимную функцию" - по такой же логике как и в неанонимную: при вызове неанонимной функции нужно точно так же распаковывать результат вызова в отдельные параметры с помощью звездочки.

Answer (score 1):

Надо распаковать кортеж прямо в передаче параметров:

```
dic = (lambda x, y: {'12': x, '10': y})(*func())
```

Comment: dic = (lambda x,y: {'12': x, '10': y})(x=func()[0],y=func()[1]) - чисто посмеяться, но должно работать;)

Comment: @Amgarak действительно, работает :)